# How to get Device name and App Version using Appium Driver

Tags: java, testng, appium

I am able to get the device android version using

```
driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("platformVersion");
```

Simillarly how I will get device name and version of app. I tried with following but no use

```
driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("deviceName");
driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("appVersion");
```

Comment: both platform version and devicename capabilities working. but appversion somehow not working

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using Adb

To get Device Name

`adb.exe -s " +deviceID+ " shell getprop ro.product.model`

To get Device OS Version

`adb.exe -s " +deviceID+ " shell getprop ro.build.version.release`

To get App Version

```
adb -s " +deviceID+ " shell dumpsys package yourPackageName | grep versionName
```

Answer (score 9):

```
driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("deviceName").toString();
driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("CapabilityType.VERSION").toString();
```

This will return you the device name and OS version as set in desired capabilities. If you want to get device information before creating driver or at run time (to check correct information of connected device) then you have to use the following to get device OS version. (adb for android and instruments for iOS)

For android -

```
adb -s " + deviceID + " shell getprop ro.build.version.release
```

For iOS -

```
instruments -s devices
```

Store the output from above command in String array and retrieve required information.

Comment: Great..! Do you have any Idea to get version of current running app

Comment: Do you have any "About" or Settings option in the app, if yes then you can check app version from these options. Else, Open Android Settings, navigate to your app, read version.

Comment: This is helpful but doesn't really answer the original question. Is there a way to use `instruments` to query (version) information about an app on a connected device? `instruments -s devices` just displays the OS version.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("deviceModel").toString()
```