# How to get exact Device Model Name in Appium from code

Tags: java, model, automated-tests, appium, device-driver

I have devices connected remotely on which Appium is run , I already know that we can add Desired capabilities during start ...
I checked out from below stackoverflow link :

[How to get Device name and App Version using Appium Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39032883/how-to-get-device-name-and-app-version-using-appium-driver#)

But , I need to get exact ***Device Model name*** as to how I can get it from code itself .

Comment: What do you mean by “exact device name”? The model? Nickname?

Comment: @MikeCollins : Yep , Need to know Model Name of Device Like Android Mi A2 , Moto E etc . The Device Model

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092118/get-device-information-such-as-product-model-from-adb-command.